# How to filter logs with rsyslog?

Tags: rsyslog

I tried [this](http://wiki.rsyslog.com/index.php/Filtering_by_program_name) but failed, here's what I did

1. Add `if $programname == 'logger' then /home/a.log` to the first line of `/etc/rsyslog.conf`
2. Restart `rsyslog`
3. When I run the command `$logger hi`, the file `/home/a.log` doesn't change

Did I miss something? By the way I'm running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.2.

Comment: can you check whether it is sending it to /var/log/messages or not?

Comment: /var/log/messages shows new message 'hi'

Comment: rsyslog does not have permissions to write at /home. Test it using /tmp/a.log

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro /tmp/a.log shows no change, I wonder whether it's the problem of '$programname'? Maybe the 'programname' of command 'logger' is not 'logger'? But I don't know other command like 'logger' to test log.

Comment: remove the if condition and test send all to /tmp/a.log